# What does a cursor.commit() in Pythons sqlite3 do?

Tags: python, sql

In Pythons sqlite3, a commit allows to implement the ACID (atomicity, consistency, isolation, durability) property of databases. The work is like:

```
...
conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(query1)
cursor.execute(query2)
conn.commit()
```

Changes in the database have to get lost, if `conn.commit()` is skipped (otherwise ACID is not fulfilled). However, I noticed that data is already written to the file database.db when `cursor.execute(query1)` is executed. The `conn.commit()` doesn't change the file at all (checksum stays identical). So: What exactly does `conn.commit()` do?

Comment: This happend if auto-commit is on. You can overwrite the behaviour with a `BEGIN` command.